# How to move bar chart labels to the Y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to have the bar labels marked on the Y-axis, instead of top of the bar charts.
Is there a way to do this?

[image]

I have quite a lengthy piece of code to recreate this plot, so reproducing only part of it. My only idea is to do it one by one through ax.patches..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
df
....
bar_plot = plt.bar(df.index, df.mean(axis=1),yerr=upper, edgecolor='indigo', color=color)  
for i in ax.patches:

    ax.text(i.get_x()+0.2, i.get_height()-5.8, \
            str(round((i.get_height()), 1)), fontsize=14, color='darkblue')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To also show the heights on the y-axis, one could introduce minor y-ticks at those positions. Optionally, gridlines can be drawn there.

For the minor y tick labels not to interfere with the major y tick labels, a possibility is to make the ticks larger which moves the ticks to the left.

Other possibilities would be to remove the major ticks entirely (`plt.yticks([])`), or to draw either of the ticks at the right side.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000, 200000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(43000, 100000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(43500, 140000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(48000, 70000, 3650)],
                  index=[1992, 1993, 1994, 1995])
means = df.mean(axis=1)
bar_plot = plt.bar(df.index, means, edgecolor='indigo',
                   color=[plt.cm.inferno(i / df.shape[0]) for i in range(df.shape[0])])
plt.xticks(df.index)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(means))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=40, color='r', labelcolor='r', labelleft=True)
plt.grid(axis='y', which='minor', color='r', ls='--')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]